# What is difference between "RedirectToAction" and "return Action()"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to redirect from Index1 to Index2 through 2 ways- like mentioned in my Index1-:

```
// RedirectToAction("Index2") 
//  return Index2()
```

I know, `RedirectToAction()` causes a new request with new url. Is there any specific reason why I should use one over other?

```
Public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index1()
    {
        // RedirectToAction("Index2") 
        //  return Index2()
    }

    public ActionResult Index2()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `RedirectToAction()` can be used as :-

```
RedirectToAction(" // action name // "," // Controller Name // ",new{ // Object Routes // })
```

with `RedirectToAction()` you can redirect to other controller actions also but not with `return Index2()`(as per your question)  you can only redirect within same controller actions.

Comment: yes, this is true. But what if have to make with in the same controller. What should I choose over other and why ?

Comment: Depends on the scenario. Redirect to action will actually invoke a redirect in the browser so the url will be specific to the other action. If you just return an action then the url will be for the current action while displaying contents of a different action which may not be the intended result.

Comment: @user3359453...i think above answer will clear your doubts..if need more help then comment...